# OTR encrypted chatroom or IM

Tags: encryption, privacy

I need a secure, encrypted environment for conducting text based interviews online.   It's for academic research purposes where data protection is paramount so there cant be any data stored on 3rd party servers.   I've looked through your older posts for help but can anyone offer any up to date info.   thanks

Comment: Hi elnet, welcome to [security.se]. Please see the [FAQ] and the About page - product recommendations are not a good fit for SE.

Comment: You might want to check out Crypho, at http://crypho.com

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really given enough information to determine what you need. Do you need anonymity in addition to encryption?

If your needs are just to have encrypted communication with the server and no third party involvement in running the chat, then the easiest thing might be setting up your own IRC server with SSL required. This would encrypt the communication to the server and your server would control all the communication. There are really lots of options and this is more of a server question than a security question as it currently stands.

Comment: sorry, I guess you can tell I'm no security expert.  anonymity is not the issue, I just need to have a totally secure environment where the communication cannot be intercepted by any external sources and the data is not stored in any place that could be accessed by any 3rd party. thanks

Comment: @Elnet101 - in that case, any chat program that you can host and that supplies encrypted communication would work.  There are a host of options and none of them are really security related.  You would probably be better off asking this on serverfault, superuser or webmaster.  Not really sure which would fit best, but this really isn't a security question.

Comment: I think you've given me what I need.  thanks for your help.